# How to use orWhere with two conditions on single column in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, eloquent

I'm trying to build a small application on `Laravel 5.5`, where I'm having a model named `Milestone` and `Task`. `Task` is having a column named `status`, the `status` is `enum` attributes column in the table with `['open', 'closed', 'accepted', 'sent']`, I want to fetch all the `task` involved in particular `Milestone` which has task with `status:` - `accepted` and `sent`,  Following is my model:

**Task**

```
public function milestone()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Team\Milestone', 'milestone_id');
}
```

And in my controller I'm trying something like this:

```
$completedTask = Task::whereHas('milestone', function ($q) use($id) {
    $q->where('unique_id', $id)->orWhere('status', ['Sent', 'Accepted']);
})->count();
```

This `orWhere` clause gives other milestone table data also.

Help me out in this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the milestones where `unique_id` is equal to some `$id` and related tasks status can be accepted or sent, you could get this data as

```
$milestones= Milestone::with(['tasks' => function ($query) {
    $query->whereIn('status', ['sent', 'accepted']);
}])
->where('unique_id', $id)
->get();
```

OR to get tasks

```
$tasks = Task::with(['milestone' => function ($query) use($id) {
    $query->where('unique_id', $id);
}])
->whereIn('status', ['sent', 'accepted'])
->get();
```

Comment: I think this is what I'm looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think your code should be like this, to get the task that has the unique_id == $id and (status = Sent or status == Accepted)

```
$completedTask = Task::whereHas('milestone', function ($q) use($id) {
    $q->where('unique_id', $id)->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where('status', 'Sent')
            ->orWhere('status', 'Accepted');
    })
})->count();
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to fetch all the Milestone which has task with status: - accepted and sent. Task is having a column named status

You should use `orWhereIn()`:

```
Milestone::whereHas('tasks', function ($q) use($id) {
        $q->where('unique_id', $id)->orWhereIn('status', ['Sent', 'Accepted']);
    })
    ->get();
```

You want to get milestones and you said `status` in the `Task` model. That's why you need to use the `Milestone` model and `tasks` relation. Also, if you want to fetch milestones and not count those, use `get()` instead of `count()`

Comment: This will give specific `milestone` `task` data? not all the `milestone->task` data?

Comment: @NitishKumar this will return all milestones that have tasks with status `sent` or `accepted` and with `unique_id = $id`

Comment: Sorry my bad, I'm calling with `unique_id` to get single `milestone` and get all relational `task` data. I don't want all milestone. I'm really sorry for presenting this in wrong way.

Comment: @NitishKumar if it's in the `milestones` table then just remove the `unique_id` part and put it into outside the `whereHas()`

Answer (score 0):

```
Milestone::whereHas('tasks', function ($q) use($id) {

    $q->where('unique_id', $id)
      ->whereIn('status', ['Sent', 'Accepted']);

})->get();
```

**orWhere** & **orWhereIn** will give you **OR** condition statement,
you should rather use where at both places to get the **AND** condition...